# "this" does not refer to the this-reference using prototype

Tags: javascript, dom-events, prototype

Today I ran into a very odd problem using Javascript's `prototype` and the `this` reference.

Basically, I have two objects. One object makes use of a `div` element and makes is possible to register an `onclick` event on the `div`. The other object makes use of this functionality and registers the `onclick` event using the first object.

Here is the code:

My first object, which takes care of the `div`:

```
DivObject = function() {};
DivObject.prototype.setClickListener = function(clickListener){
    document.getElementById("myDiv").onclick = function(e){
        clickListener(e);
    };
};
```

My second object uses this functionality:

```
MainObject = function(){
    this.myString = "Teststring";
    this.divObj = new DivObject();
    this.divObj.setClickListener(this.handleClick);
};

MainObject.prototype.handleClick = function(e){
    // do something with e
};
```

The problem is, that inside `MainObject.prototype.handleClick`, the `this` reference refers to the `window` object, not to the `MainObject`. So, `console.log(this)` inside this function logs `[Object window]`.

[You can see this behaviour on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/gT4Eu/3/)

As a workaround, I use the `setClickListener` function as follows:

```
var thisRef = this;
this.divObj.setClickListener(function(e){
    thisRef.handleClick(e);
});
```

Now, the `this` reference in my `handleClick` function refers to my `MainObject` (as I want it to be).

[See this workaround on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/gT4Eu/1/)

My questions are:

Why does the `this` reference one time refer to the `window` object and one time to the `this` reference of my object? Is it overridden somewhere? I always thought using `this` in my object I can be sure that it is really the `this` reference of my object? Is the workaround I am using now the way how this problem should be solved or are there any other, better way to handle this case?

Comment: How `this` works is described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Comment: Because `this` is set by how you call the function, not how you create or assign it (except for ES5 bind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions:

> Why does the this reference one time refer to the window object and one time to the this reference of my object?

Other than using *bind*, the value of a function's `this` is set by how the function is called. When you do:

```
this.divObj.setClickListener(this.handleClick);
```

you are assigning a function reference, so the function is called later without any qualification (i.e. it's called as just *handleClick* rather than *this.handleClick*). On entering the function, because its `this` isn't set by the call, it will default to the global (window) object, or in strict mode remain undefined.

> Is it overridden somewhere?

No, the value of `this` is set on entering an execution context. You can't overwrite it or directly assign to it, you can only set it in the call (e.g. as a method of an object, using *new*, *apply*, *call*) or using *bind* (also, arrow functions adopt the *this* of their enclosing lexical execution context).

> I always thought using this in my object I can be sure that it is really the this reference of my object?

At the point you make the assignment, `this` is what you expect. But you are assigning a reference to a funciotn, not calling the function, so its `this` isn't set at that moment but later when it's called.

> Is the workaround I am using now the way how this problem should be solved or are there any other, better way to handle this case?

Your work around is fine (and a common fix), it creates a closure so may have minor memory consequences but nothing serious. For very old versions of IE it would create a memory leak due to the circular reference involving a DOM object, but that's fixed.

The *bind* solution is probably better from a clarity and perhaps maintenance viewpoint. Remember to include a "monkey patch" for browsers that don't have built–in support for *bind*.

Please post code on SO, there is no guarantee that code posted elsewhere will continue to be accessible. The work around code:

```
MainObject = function(){
    this.myString = "Teststring";
    this.divObj = new DivObject();
    var thisRef = this;
    this.divObj.setClickListener(function(e){
        thisRef.handleClick(e);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answering all my questions, now it is clear to me what is happening :)

Comment: "*so the function is called without any qualification*" - the relevant line to determine that is the `clickListener(e);`, not the `setClickListener` call.

Comment: @Bergi—updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could fix this by using ***[.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)***:

```
this.divObj.setClickListener(this.handleClick.bind(this));
```

***[See the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/gT4Eu/4/)***

Comment: I already managed to make it work using the workaround mentioned in my question. What are the advantages of your approach?

Comment: Can you also answer my other questions?